# ios remove object from nsmutable array and reindex the array

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

What would be the best way of remove object from nsmutable array and reindex the array ?. What I mean be reindex is for example:

in array of 20 objects I remove object with index 11. I have the 19 objects but the object on index 11 it would be nil. What I want is to have the array with the 19 objects with from 0..18.

Comment: NSMutableArray does the "reindexing" automatically for you. Use whatever method you want to remove objects from the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use

```
- (void)removeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

It will automatically reindex the array because "all elements beyond `index` are moved by subtracting 1 from their index".

See [NSMutableArray Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObjectAtIndex%3a) for details.